# Powershell - Adding users to AD group from a CSV file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I know this has been done to death but im useing this as a learning experience with powershell. Could someone take a look at my code and tell me where i am going wrong? Noob code warning!

```
# 
# Add User to an AD Group
# 
# 

# get arguements and quit if they dont exist 
$CSV = $args[0]
$GROUP = $args[1]
if (! $CSV) {
Write-Host "Please format this command as 'AddUsersToGroup <csv file> <AD group>'"
Write-Host "CSV file must have the header 'UserName' with AD usernames following"
exit
}


# Read csv file for users and add to AD group
Import-module ActiveDirectory  
Import-CSV "$CSV" | % {  

# Get existing users from AD group
$ExistingGroup = "Get-ADGroupMember $GROUP | Select-Object SamAccountName"

# create new array removing existing users from the csv
$NewGroup = $ExistingGroup | where {$CSV -notcontains $_}

# add the users to the AD Group from the new array
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $NewGroup -Member $_.UserName
exit
}
```

Comment: `Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' require
d by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\temp\AddUsersToGroup.ps1:27 char:28
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <<<<  $NewGroup -Member $_.UserName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember`

Answer (score 1):

try delete double quote here:

```
$ExistingGroup = Get-ADGroupMember $GROUP | Select-Object SamAccountName
```

with quote you're assign a string value to variable not the results of your commands